# How do people create restful data services in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, amazon-s3, datastore

Where do developers store their data? I heard that it can be hard to access S3 with the existing libraries and you need to update all URL calls using GAE's methods. Do developers typically find other ways to access S3 or do they use some other sort of storage (Google Storage is not public yet) such as databases? Does google provide anything for this, what is the "ideal" way that app engine would solve the problem of having users get and post data to persistent storage through app engine?

Answer (score 2):

GAE provides the [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/) API, built on their [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html).

There's many good questions on the GAE Datastore [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gae-datastore?sort=votes).